# Calculate the payment

Tags: c++

```
double total,grandtotal;
double amount, change=0;

total=day* price* noRoom;
grandtotal=total*1.16;

cout<<"\t\tPlease enter your amount:RM";
cin>>amount;



while (amount < grandtotal)
{
    cout << "\t\tPlease enter a valid amount:RM";
    cin >> amount;
}


change=amount-grandtotal;
 if (amount > grandtotal)
{
    cout<<"\t\tYour change is:    "<<change <<endl;
    cout<<"\t\tThank You, Have a nice day! \n";
    cout<<"\t\t Please come again  \n";

}
 else   if( amount == grandtotal) //why this statement can't run if my amount is also equal to the grandtotal???

{
    cout<<"\t\tThank You, Have a nice day! \n";
    cout<<"\t \tPlease come again \n";
}
```

Comment: Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: His problem is described as comment in his else if

Comment: Put the question outside the code block and people might retract their downvotes.

Comment: @Elmi Being a beginner in programming and in conversation is different. If someone expects us to be mindreaders (or looking through some code to find english sentences) to understand something...

Answer (score 1):

Your `else if` might be executed but most likely it won't happen, because `double` values precision is relatively high so there will be difference.

If you set the precision smaller for example that should work.

eg 2.11 == 2.11 rather than 2.15151523 == 2.15151524

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349323/setting-the-precision-of-a-double-without-using-stream-ios-baseprecision) question might help you doing so.

Comment: so wannna include the <iomanip> to set the precision for all output?

Comment: You can do that but that will only affect the output. I've put in a link in my answer where you can read about a way to achieve the precision you want.

Answer (score 1):

My observation is that you are using floating point values for financial transactions. This is not a good idea. The representation of floating point numbers can be approximate for certain floating point values. It would be much better to use (long) integers to represent the pence/cents, and then represent the larger denomination in the output function.

That way your test will work.

In some contexts you may want to compare floats then use a very small constant floating point value perhaps called epsilon and have the test.

```
if (fabs(amount - grandtotal) < epsilon)
{
   cout<<"\t\tThank You, Have a nice day! \n";
   cout<<"\t \tPlease come again \n";
}
```