# Display 12digit double or int as full instead of 3.23223e+9 on QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, numbers, qcustomplot

C++ is displaying a number `3232235975` on `QLabel` as `3.23223e+9`, while on `QCustomPlot` axis as `3.23223*10^9`. I am not involving stream such as `std::cout`, that is why `std::setprecision` doesn't work for my case.

Am actually working with `QCustomPlot` to plot graph with 12digit numbers on the axis. Is this C++ issue or is it `QCustomPlot` mechanism issue? How can I display all the digits of the number?

Thanks

EDIT: After receiving hint of `setNumberPrecision()` from @saeed, now the coordination is still showing in 2.88798e+9 format. Now that the axis is already showing 4000000000, I want the coordination `QLabel` (shown in the image I attached)  also display 2887984335.

I am getting the coordination and setting it to a QLabel like this.

```
double x2 = ui->widget_graph2->xAxis->pixelToCoord(_mouseEvent->pos().x());
double y2 = ui->widget_graph2->yAxis-pixelToCoord(_mouseEvent->pos().y());
ui->label_xcoord_2->setNum(x2);
ui->label_ycoord_2->setNum(y2);
```

And I'm setting the plot data using `setData()` like this

```
QVector<double> x2(i), y2(i);
for(int o = 0; o <= i; o++){
    double dSec = arrayIPxTime[o][0] - startSecond;
    double dMin = dSec/60;
    double ipv4addr = arrayIPxTime[o][1];
    x2[o] = dMin;
    y2[o] = ipv4addr;
}
ui->widget_graph2->addGraph(0);
ui->widget_graph2->graph(0)->setData(x2, y2);
ui->widget_graph2->installEventFilter(this);
```

[image: Working with QCustomPlot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: I am not printing it. Using cout is using stream. In my case it's not stream related. I have already checked that post before I posted this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display coordinates in your wanted format

```
ui->label_xcoord_2->setNum(x2);
ui->label_ycoord_2->setNum(y2);
```

Use `void setText(const QString &)` method for QLabel and pass

```
QString QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6)
```

As parameter with your wanted format and precision:

> Format    Meaning
>
> e format as [-]9.9e[+|-]999
>
> E format as [-]9.9E[+|-]999
>
> f format as [-]9.9
>
> g use e or f format, whichever is the most concise
>
> G use E or f format, whichever is the most concise

Comment: Thank you so much, solve my entire issue. You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create following just as `qCustomPlot` sample set axis properties like codes bellow.

```
// setup look of bottom tick labels:
customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelRotation(30);
customPlot->xAxis->ticker()->setTickCount(9);
customPlot->xAxis->setNumberFormat("ebc");
customPlot->xAxis->setNumberPrecision(1);
customPlot->xAxis->moveRange(-10);
// make top right axes clones of bottom left axes. Looks prettier:
customPlot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();
```

setNumberPrecision sets number of float digits if you set it to zero may show all digits in plot axis.
setNumberFormat("g") also may show all digits too , anyway qCustomplot try to show values alongside axis as beauty can be.

Here is  a preview.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: Thanks for instant reply, checked the doc and it's for stream use only. How if I want to set it like this ---- `ui->label_xcoord_1->setNum(x3);` Tried this ---- `ui->label_xcoord_1->setNum(std::setprecision(12)<<x3)` but it didn't work