# C++: How do I set precision for the return value of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a `double Variance()` function with the return value rounded to 4th decimal point.
For example, if the result is `5.2992124` then it returns `5.2992`, and returns `8.9914` if the result is `8.991382`.

I know that there's `cout << setprecision(~)`, `printf("%.4d, ~")`, but I'm not sure how to utilize that in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350132/896012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you need this for.  It seems unusual to require a variance value rounded to some significant figures.  In any case, you can round off your `double` as follows:

```
double rounded = 1e-4 * std::round(1e4 * value);
```

This multiplies by 10000 and rounds to a whole number, then divides by 10000.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to first convert the value into an integer. 
You can use c++'s pow() function defined in the header cmath:

```
pow(base, exponent)
```

In your example : 5.2992124.

(unsigned int) 5.2992124 * pow(10, 4).

This would yield the value 52992.124 which then becomes 52992 after truncation. 
You can then again convert it into a double by dividing it with pow(10, 4) and there you have it : 5.2992 as you wanted.